# Using the word "Disposition" as a Verb

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know disposition means a persons inherent qualities of mind and character and it is a noun. i know you would say "he has a very quiet brooding disposition" but my roommate was cleaning the house and said, "will you help me move the table? I don't want to slide it and disposition the rug."

i told him using disposition in that context was wrong and we argued. i felt he should've used reposition instead of disposition. using disposition he would've said "can you help me move the table so as to not affect the disposition of the rug"

can you use disposition as a verb or is it strictly a noun?

Comment: Ultimately, as long as your interlocutor understands what you mean, then you're correct, if not "correct". That said, "disposition" is an unusual formulation, and likely a novel example of linguistic analogy. For example, the plural of "cow" was once "kine", but as pluralization via adding an "s" became more common, the plural became "cows". In the same way, I imagine your roommate had internalized the pattern seen in something like "arm" and "disarm" and applied it to "position".

Answer (score 2):

Since this was spoken, I expect that your roommate actually said "dis-position", which is a negative form of the verb "position"; this negative form would mean "to move something away from its preferred or customary location.  A perfectly understandable use of the standard productive prefix *dis-*; the fact that it produces a word that sounds identical but has a different meaning is unfortunate, but does not render the utterance incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you may be seeking is *displace*.

*I do not wish to displace the rug*.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that your roommate based his argument on analogy to *reposition*, which does indeed serve as a verb in everyday English. *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) also has an entry for *reposition* as a noun ("the act of repositing : the state of being reposited"), but in my experience that form of the word isn't common.

I agree with WS2 that you're better off using *displace* (or for that matter, *move*) than making *disposition* a verb. I also advise against using *imposition* and *composition* as verbs, even though you could probably come up with a rationale for doing so.

Comment: or a slip from the word **misposition**

Comment: Good point, Oldcat. Also, if the speaker wanted to coin a new term, _de-position_ might be a better word choice than _dis-position_ in spoken English, since it sounds less like a homophone of _deposition_ than _dis-position_ does of _disposition_.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-verb-for/disposition.html

According to wordhippo, he used the word precisely correctly.
Disposition is based on the word dispose. Disposition can mean to remove or just change position.

https://www.mass.gov/districtmunicipal-courts-rules-for-probation-violation-proceedings/rule-8-finding-and-disposition
In this  article, disposition means the final result as an outcome of a parole violation hearing (i believe it applies much more generally in judicial settings).  The judge has 4 choices, his choice becomes the disposition.

While I can not claim it conforms to proper usage, it is common, in my experience, to use the word disposition when talking about how to deal with something.
When a part is sent in because a customer claims it is defective, the technician reviews the paperwork and inspects the part.
He can disposition the part as  return to customer, scrap, return to manufacturer etc.

In both the parole example and my business example, disposition is really the choice that is made, and its a noun of course. But it is common, in my experience, for the same word to be used to mean 'engaging in the making of the choice', hence a verb.

I guess dispositioning would be an option, I cant say I have ever heard someone use dispositioning.

Answer (score -1):

There is no entry for "disposition" as a verb in the OED.

Whereas absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, in this case, the verbal use of "disposition" (other than that mentioned by Hellion in Oct 2014 - and that is marginal) should be regarded as wrong.